# Jenkins Dedicated Dashboard Server

Tags: jenkins, dashboard

I am in need of setting up Dedicated Jenkins Dashboard server, which houses jobs from multiple server.
Each jobs will be configured on seperate build machine.

Can anyone please suggest what is the best approach ??

Note: Master/Slave config is not an option since i want the entire build to be done at the build server and Dashboard server managing and reporting the respective projects

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are asking for here.  Could you clarify on your Note: Master/Slave...

Comment: I would reconsider running Jenkins in a master slave configuration.

Comment: Let me give a brief overview of my requirements. I've projects setup on their own build machine with jenkins installed on all of them(probably behind firewall) and one centralized jenkins dashboard server which communicates with each build machine and manages all the projects.